# Harmonized Sentinel-2 Landsat

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, sentinel-2

Recently, I recognized a new dataset in Google Earth Engine called the HLSL30: HLS-2 Landsat Operational Land Imager Surface Reflectance and TOA Brightness Daily Global 30m. I am wondering about the spatial data coverage of this dataset as they say it is global but I cannot find tiles in Europe for example in GEE. Either with a large time search of several years, only few regions appear to have the data.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/HLS/HLSL30/v002")
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2015-04-25', '2016-03-28')).filterBounds(AOI).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVERAGE', 30)); 
AOI is a shapefile (asset) I use usually in all my previous codes and works fine

Comment: Okay so it is likely that the code works it is just you are expecting more images...but that may not be the case. For example if you are getting 5 images, it may be that there are only 5 images within your AOI, during this time period, with less than 30% cloud coverage. Remove the cloud coverage filter, does this give you more images?

Comment: Thank you, I have just tried to do that but actually I am getting 0 images even if I remove the clouds percentage filter. Even when I remove the AOI, I get only some few images in India, south America and Russia and not more

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64064607 "ingestion is still ongoing" (oct 17th 2023}